# How to add libusb to java swing netbeans project?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans-7, libusb

`libusb` is installed on the Ubuntu host running Netbeans 7.1 but is not an option in `Projects > Libraries > Right Click > Add Library.` There are various libusb.so and libusb.a files on this host but no libusb.jar files.

I ended up using the [javax.usb](http://sourceforge.net/projects/javax-usb/) jar since the only wrapper I could find for libusb did not support v1.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create your own library by **Tools > Libraries** and click **New Library** button.
Then you can give a name to your library and add the required jars to that library.

After that if you repeat your process it should showup.

Answer (score 2):

You need to create and add a new library to your project/netbeans, this can be done by navigating to: *File->Project Properties->Tools > Libraries->Create->* enter your libraries name i.e *libusb* then *Ok->Add JAR/Folder* and select the appropriate jars to include.